# normal test to student test, logic behind it

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Let's say we have :
$$ X_i  \sim \ N( \mu, \sigma^2 ) $$
iid

I'm constructing this test function, in order to test two hypothesis on $\mu$ : $$ \mathbb { 1} {\{ \sum^n X_i < q_a \} } $$
where $q_a$ is the $a$-quantile of $$ P_{ \mu_0 } ( \sum^n X_i < q_a  ) $$

If I know $\sigma$, this test is just fine. Because then I can rewrite the test function as : 
$$ \mathbb { 1} \{ \frac{  \sum X_i - n \mu_0 }{ \sigma \sqrt{n} } < \phi^{-1} (a) \}  $$

But if I don't know $\sigma$, how can I handle things ? I have been told to replace it by $S$, such that : $$ S^2 = \frac 1 {n-1} \sum^n (X_i - \overline X)^2 $$

But how do you conclude that the test is now :

$$ \mathbb { 1} \{ \frac{  \sum X_i - n \mu_0 }{ S \sqrt{n} } < t_{n-1, a} \}  $$
where $t_{n-1, a} $ is the $a$-quantile of the student law with n-1 degrees of freedom?

Comment: Please also state whether both these hypothesis are simple or composite? If they are simple then the NP lemma can be used to derived the most powerful test.

Comment: Well i used the NP lemma for finding the test in the case of the normal distribution. I made the hypothesis I knew sigma. And then now i need to take care of it because i don't know him. It is in the case unilateral, where i m trying to determine whether the expectancy is greater or lower than 0.

Comment: Are $H_0$ and $H_1$ simple hypothesis?

Comment: No. H_0 is mu greater than or equal to 0, H_1 mu lower than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that we are testing for two different things. The first one is a test for a normal where we know $ \sigma $, the second for an unknown $\sigma$.  We aren't replacing anything in the first case to get to the second. The thing is it is two totally different ideas. The only link I found is that :

$ \bar{X} $ is independant to $ S^2$. Hence :

$$ \frac {\bar{X}  - \mu } { \frac {S}{ \sqrt n }  } = \frac {        \frac { \sqrt n (\bar{X} - \mu )  }{ \sigma }       }{\sqrt {\frac { (n-1) S^2 }{(n-1) \sigma^2 } }     } \sim t_{n-1} $$

In both case we want a test with $\alpha$ level of risk, so take the $1-\alpha$ quantile. Which leads us to the result mentionned in the question.

So the conclusion is, we have two different tests, asssociated to two different random variables, depending on whether we know the variance or not.

Answer (score -2):

It is well known that $S_{XX}/\sigma^2= \frac {1} {n\sigma^2} \sum (X_i - \overline X)^2$ has the $\chi_{n-1}^2$ distribution.

It is also known that if $Z$ is a standard normal, and $X$ is $\chi_k^2$ then $T=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{X/n}}$ has the $t_k$ distribution.

I'll let you see how to apply that here

Comment: 1) I have this formula for the chi squared distribution : $$ \frac {n-1} {\sigma^2 } S^2 \sim  \chi_{n-1}^2 $$
2) I know that. I ve written it in my post. What's next?

Comment: I dont think you want to be finding a $q_a$ such that $ P_{ \mu_0 } ( \sum^n X_i < q_a  )$ Instead you want a region which has a fixed size. You know that the variable I've denoted T has the t distribution, so you can write down a region in which $\mathbb{P}(T<k)=\alpha$, and from that deduce a test